# R# 10 find method implementor in all GAC assemblies

Tags: resharper

When looking for a interface/abstract method implementors, is it possible to extend search scope outside current solution?

Answer (score 1):

No. ReSharper only works with the current solution, and the libraries referenced by the current solution. You can use the Assembly Explorer window, or dotPeek as a standalone app to load any and all other assemblies, even from the GAC, and you'll be able to search for implementations over everything that's loaded.

Comment: Which effectively means "Yes it is possible", doesn't it? ) Also worth noting that in order to extend the scope to include loaded libraries, you'll need to use [Find Usages Advanced](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Finding_Usages_Advanced.html) instead of the regular Find Usages.